# Why is this cURL failing?

Tags: php, curl

I have tried many things and settings and finally came to this code which should have worked but it's not working. The URL is a valid one.

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'TESTDATA');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
$response = explode(chr(10),curl_exec($curlSession));
$response1 = curl_getinfo( $curlSession );
curl_close ($curlSession);
$data = implode('', $response);
var_dump($data);
```

This is the response from curl_getinfo()

```
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => -8172
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.140683
[namelookup_time] => 0.124828
[connect_time] => 0.125422
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 34.194.49.253
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 172.31.63.119
[local_port] => 45116
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: @Joe Probably `[http_code] => 0`.

Comment: How did you test that the URL works? Is it your own, or does it require a specific user agent?

Comment: It works now when I set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false

Comment: I think there was a problem with the SSL of the server

Comment: sorry... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now when I set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false .I think there was a problem with the SSL of the server

This is the final code. Use it if your server has SSL problems

```
function getCurlDATA($url){
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'PRICELESSDATA');
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = explode(chr(10),curl_exec($curlSession));
    curl_close ($curlSession);
    $data = implode('', $response);
    return $data; 
 }
```